# Filtering data source so a user can only see their own info

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

On one of my screens I have a table that shows information about customer companies. Now I'm trying to filter the data source so a user from company X can only view the info for company X, and not the info for company Y or Z. I have created a table (CustomerUser) that contains the guid of an aspnet_User, and the CustomerID so a company can create multiple users.

Here's what I have so far, but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop since it throws a StackOverflowException.

```
partial void Customers_Filter(ref Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter)
    {
        //if (!Application.Current.User.HasPermission(Permissions.SecurityAdministration))
        //{
            //Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;                
            Guid guid = new Guid("1657d378-4b8b-ed4e-f928-bb48fc83bf18");

            IEnumerator cusUsers = this.CustomerUsers.GetEnumerator();

            CustomerUser current;
            CustomerUser found = null;
            while (cusUsers.MoveNext())
            {
                current = (CustomerUser)cusUsers.Current;

                if (current.GebruikerID == guid)
                {
                    found = current;
                }
            };

            try
            {                
                if (found != null)
                {
                    filter = e => e.CustomerID == found.Customer1.CustomerID;
                }
                else
                {
                    filter = e => e.CustomerID == "-1";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        //}
    }
```

Comment: Create a view with "where guid = userguid" condition, let the users access the view only, not the base table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I have not worked with Lightswitch for very long.

Comment: Neither have I... My comment is more of a general solution, don't even know if it works in your specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, for anyone with the same isue stumbling upon this question: I've added a new query and preprocessed that, instead of filtering the data set, this fixed my problem. Like so:

```
partial void CustomersByLoggedInUser_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Customer> query)
    {
    if (!Application.Current.User.HasPermission(Permissions.SecurityAdministration))
    {
        Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;                

        IEnumerator cusUsers = this.CustomerUsers.GetEnumerator();

        CustomerUser current;
        CustomerUser found = null;
        while (cusUsers.MoveNext())
        {
            current = (CustomerUser)cusUsers.Current;

            if (current.GebruikerID == guid)
            {
                found = current;
            }
        };

        try
        {                
            if (found != null)
            {
                filter = e => e.CustomerID == found.Customer1.CustomerID;
            }
            else
            {
                filter = e => e.CustomerID == "-1";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The enumerator for `CustomerUsers` most likely has a bug in it.

However, would should add a `break` when the correct user is found.

```
       while (cusUsers.MoveNext())
       {
            current = (CustomerUser)cusUsers.Current;

            if (current.GebruikerID == guid)
            {
                found = current;
                break;  // stop searching 
            }
        };
```

**OR**

```
       while (found == null && cusUsers.MoveNext())
       {
            current = (CustomerUser)cusUsers.Current;

            if (current.GebruikerID == guid)
            {
                found = current;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Hello Richard, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't seem to fix the StackoverflowException. I will leave the break; in the code though, I had not thought of adding that.